Display styling won't change


const hamburgerMenuBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-button");

hamburgerMenuBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hamburgerPopupToggle()
});

function hamburgerPopupToggle() {
  console.log("Button pressed");
  const hamburgerMenuPopup = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-popup");
  if (hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display === "block") {
    hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display = "none";
    console.log(hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display);
  } else {
    hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display = "block";
    console.log(hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display);
  }
}
#hamburger-menu-popup { display: none; }
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <span id="hamburger-menu-button">menu</span>
  <div id="hamburger-menu-popup">
    <div id="home-button">Home</div>
    <div id="create-post">Create a Post</div>
  </div>
</div>



The popup opens
(https://i.sstatic.net/4hlVl4VL.png)
But then instead of setting display style back to "none", it sets it to "unset !important", BUT it logs that it's "none" (https://i.sstatic.net/DadeuwQ4.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/bmL9RzHU.png)
So, for some reason it logs what was supposed to happen, but the CSS doesn't change whatsoever. (It changes, but not as expected)

I've created a runnable Stack Snippet from your code (and screenshot markup) and there doesn't appear to be any problem. This is not reproducible. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]

Just like @phil , its working fine for me too.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your code works fine for me, so there's probably something else causing the issue for you (some plugin probably?).
I recommend just toggling a class on your menu-element. This has two advantages:

You don't need the if in your JS code
You can do all styling in CSS

JS:
let hamburgerMenuPopup = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-popup");
hamburgerMenuPopup.classList.toggle("show");

CSS:
#hamburger-menu-popup{
display:none;
}

#hamburger-menu-popup.show{
display:block;
}


** EDIT **
The solution was to not only change the display to "block", but also visibility to "visible", so the final code is now:
const  hamburgerMenuBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-button");
hamburgerMenuBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){hamburgerPopupToggle()});

function hamburgerPopupToggle() {
    console.log("Button pressed");
    const hamburgerMenuPopup = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-popup");
    if (hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display === "block") {
      hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display = "none";
      hamburgerMenuPopup.style.visibility = "hidden";
      console.log(hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display);
    } else {
      hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display = "block";
      hamburgerMenuPopup.style.visibility = "visible";
      console.log(hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display);
    }
}


this is posted as an answer, but it isn't an answer. Consider removing this 'answer' and actually editing you question likewise.

Please try like this :


const hamburgerMenuBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-button");

hamburgerMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let hamburgerMenuPopup = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-popup");
    if (hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementById("hamburgerMenuPopup").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hamburgerMenuPopup").style.display = "none";
    }
});





const hamburgerMenuBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-button");

hamburgerMenuBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
   let hamburgerMenuPopup = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-popup");
    if (hamburgerMenuPopup.style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementById("hamburgerMenuPopup").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hamburgerMenuPopup").style.display = "none";
    }
});
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <span id="hamburger-menu-button">menu</span>
  <div id="hamburger-menu-popup">
    <div id="home-button">Home</div>
    <div id="create-post">Create a Post</div>
  </div>
</div>





#hamburger-menu-popup { display: none; }




Please explain how this solve the issue - "Try this" is not an answer
